# Autosys API access

Tags: autosys

I need to programmatically start some autosys jobs. Is there any api available in Java, perl etc for Job management other then usual command line approach.

I m using Autosys r11.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Autosys R11 has a Java API. See the ca.com web site and download the CA Workload Automation AE API Reference guide for the documentation.

CA Workload Automation AE is CA's latest rename of Autosys

Answer (score 0):

Use a calendar to tell Autosys what day of month you need to run the job.

The commands to launch calendar tool are autocal (graphical editor) and autocal_asc (CLI editor). It should be in $/etc/autosys on ur server.

Answer (score 0):

There is a perl library [CA::WAAE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CA%3a%3aWAAE) which can get job info and/or start jobs. Another library [CA::AutoSys](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CA%3a%3aAutoSys) is for an older version of Autosys.